# I'm getting a blank error message dialog - what is it trying to say?

Tags: eclipse, messagedialog

An error message dialog pops up when I try to run a Compare in Eclipse, but it seems the cat's got its tongue.

How do I find out what it's trying to say?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Best course of action is to check the `.log` file.  You'll find that in the `.metadata` directory of your workspace.